# How to find databases associated based on server credentials in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to find the associated Databases of a particular user based on Server authentication credentials in SQL server.

Comment: you mean to say ownerwise database names in a perticular server

Comment: yes @POHH.when when we give a username and password,it should display all the databases related to him

Comment: why not you put some code here by which you are passing credentials

Answer (score 0):

as per my understading you want this .it will give list of databases based on the username using `sys.databases`

```
SELECT name FROM sys.databases where suser_sname( owner_sid ) = 'trainee' order by name
```

you should pass username in place of trainee

Comment: I gave two textboxes for username and password in asp.net form,then based on the given credentials it should display associated databases

Answer (score 0):

Once you connect to SQL Server using provides UserName/Password, You can query sys.databases view:

```
SELECT  [DatabaseName] = name
FROM    [sys].[databases]
WHERE   HAS_DBACCESS([name]) = 1
```